# uwsgi installation error in windows 7

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

Trying to install uwsgi according to [documentation.](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) I'm getting the below error on Windows 7.

What should I do?

```
(uwsgi-tutorial) C:\Users\Home\Videos\uwsgi-tutorial\mysite>pip install uwsgi
Collecting uwsgi
Using cached uwsgi-2.0.11.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "c:\users\home\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-04g1m6\uwsgi\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    import uwsgiconfig as uc
  File "uwsgiconfig.py", line 8, in <module>
    uwsgi_os = os.uname()[0]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'uname'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\home\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-04g1m6\uwsgi
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`uWSGI` can be compiled on Windows only using `cygwin`. There is no such thing as `uname` in normal Windows console, but it exists inside `cygwin`. If you're already in cygwin console, try to run `uname` command, if that exists, check if `os.uname()` in python inside `cygwin` is also working.

Comment: I get the same error on cygwin. However entering uname command shows result

Comment: So clearly there is something wrong with your cygwin. If you do have windows 10, you can try bash. It can be installed from Windows developer settings.

Comment: I have windows 7 64 bit, installing and updating cygwin helped me accomplish what I needed.  Also @GwynBleidD, I was able to run `uname` and after importing `os` in the python interpreter, I was able to successfully run `os.uname()`

Comment: I have also windows 7 64 bit, and os.uname() does not work. How did you update cygwin? After starting cygwin setup.exe, I get `nothing to install/update`. Maybe I am using an old or broken version.

Answer (score 5):

Latest news from the front, uWSGI perfectly works on Windows 10 in bash on Ubuntu on Windows

As Linux subsystem still in beta, i'd not recommend for production usage, however this will cover all dev needs.

P.S. i know that op ask about Windows 7, however as Windows 10 and Linux subsystem come to Windows world later, i think i can leave this here.

Answer (score 2):

uWSGI can be compiled on Windows using Cygwin. But unfortunately, I was getting the same message with the Cygwin.

Here I am sharing the other way to install uWSGI on windows.

**Step 1:** **[Download](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Download.html) the stable release and extract the tar file**

**Step 2:** **Open *uwsgiconfig.py* and import platform then replace `os.uname()[index]` with `platform.uname()[index]`**

Change

```
uwsgi_os = os.uname()[0]
uwsgi_os_k = re.split('[-+_]', os.uname()[2])[0]
uwsgi_os_v = os.uname()[3]
uwsgi_cpu = os.uname()[4]
```

To

```
import platform
uwsgi_os =  platform.uname()[0]
uwsgi_os_k = re.split('[-+_]',  platform.uname()[2])[0]
uwsgi_os_v =  platform.uname()[3]
uwsgi_cpu =  platform.uname()[4]
```

**Step 3:** **Run `python setup.py install`**

Note: You may need to [install GCC and configure it](https://dev.to/gamegods3/how-to-install-gcc-in-windows-10-the-easier-way-422j).

Comment: After doing all steps getting this error `fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Same, also getting `fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory`. I am just trying to do some programming on my Windows gaming PC on the side. Always run into shite like this. Seems never worth ;(