# uWSGI failed installation on Windows with Cygwin

Tags: python-3.x, pip, uwsgi

today I have tried to install uwsgi on Windows and this trouble:
[[Cygwin error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0rcf.png)]

I tried this command pip3 install setup.py, and nothing change. I want other solutions for this problem.

My specs:
Python 3.5.2
Windows 7
Pip: 10.0.1

Comment: If you only want to install uwsgi on windows, you can see...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163910/uwsgi-installation-error-in-windows-7